# Updating Android ArrayList after data retrieval from Firebase FireStore

Tags: android, firebase, arraylist, google-cloud-firestore

I have implemented Firebase Firestore into my android application and it is retrieving data fine.

There is a calculation performed to sum up the values that are stored in the Firestore.

However, I believe with how I designed my code, there could be possible limitations on what can be done.

I have retrieved the data from Firestore and stored it into an ArrayList. So I can already see that when the ArrayList is initially populated from Firestore, any new data would not have updated the ArrayList.

I was thinking of maybe implementing a refresh button or a slide to refresh, but not too sure how to go about it.

The code is the same for the 2 sum sections and setting the value into the textview.

```
personTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.personSumValue);
    final ArrayList<UserPaymentModel> personArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    db.collection("userspayment").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            if (queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: LIST EMPTY");
                return;
            } else {
                List<UserPaymentModel> types = queryDocumentSnapshots.toObjects(UserPaymentModel.class);

                // Add all to your list
                personArrayList.addAll(types);

                //Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + mArrayList.get(2).getAmount());
                double sum = 0;
                for (UserPaymentModel u : personArrayList) {
                    if (u.getName().equals("Person1")) {
                        sum += Double.valueOf(u.getAmount());
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: " + sum);
                personSumTextView.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
            }
        }
    });
```

[image]

Basically there are 4 values and adding up the 2 values based on certain criteria will sum up the different values. If I add a new value, the recyclerview will be updated, but the sum shown at the top half of the screen does not update until I close and reopen the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the values every time something is added on your Firestore Collection then you need to use a `SnapshotListener` instead of just getting the values once.

To do so, you need to replace `db.collection("userspayment").get()` with `db.collection("userspayment").addSnapshotListener(EventListener)`. You can find more details in the documentation : [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

With this implementation no need to add a refresh as the data will come in real-time. All you need to do is to notify your Adapter that the data has changed using `notifyDataSetChanged()`